# ANTLR: How to avoid re-parsing entire file when user modifies text

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

**edit:** For those interested/who want to see exactly what I'm doing, the source code of my app can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/Repository).

---

I'm building a code editor app with C# that offers syntax highlighting. I'm currently using [ANTLR for C#](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs) to parse the code in order to highlight it. So far, my app can highlight the code really fast when the user initially opens the file. However, I haven't written any code to re-highlight the text when the user starts editing it.

I want the editor to perform well for large files, so I don't want to re-parse the entire file each time the user types a character. I did a bit of research, and it seems like what I'm looking for is an incremental parser. Unfortunately, it seems like ANTLR v4 [can't do incremental parsing](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1104), so I'm unsure what to do.

My question is: is there another approach I can take, using ANTLR, to not freeze the app whenever the user types? I'm really hesitant to give up on ANTLR since there are [a bunch of free grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) available for it, so it's not much work to add support for a new language. I've looked into TextMate grammars, VSCode uses lots of them, but I don't understand them and there are no C# libraries available to manipulate them.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you sure you even need to parse the file for syntax highlighting? Often all you need for syntax highlighting is the token stream, which is not only faster to calculate, but it's also easier to just re-tokenize a small part of a file. This isn't enough if you want to use semantic information like if you want to highlight instance variables differently than local variables for example. But if all you want is one color for Identifiers, another for this set of keywords etc., token-based highlighting is easier and more performant.

Comment: Are you aware of [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview) ?

Comment: @sepp2k You're correct, I could just tokenize the source code if I wanted all identifiers to be the same color, but then the code will look almost monotone. I want to color type names differently than local variable identifiers, for example.

Comment: @GuyCoder Yes, that's what I'm going to use to highlight C# in fact. However, that doesn't help me highlight other languages like Java (I'm *writing* the app in C#, but I'm not only dealing with C# files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't parse after every keystroke, but I do parse the entire file.  This works great for intermediate-size files in the domain-specific languages I've created.   Instead of trying parse only parts of the file, I use a mixed approach, parsing when the first of either of three conditions exists:

1. User types *n* characters
2. A timer has said that there's no change in *m* milliseconds.
3. For some grammars, user types line terminator/separator character;

Bottom line is, you might be surprised at how much time people spend pausing and thinking as they're typing in anything that imposes a grammar on them.  These pauses can be exploited to do useful work while the user thinks, even for 400 milliseconds.  I use #1 and #2 in the DSLs I've created for work due to their syntax.

The "no change" clock gets reset after every keystroke event and the *n* characters counter of course gets set when parsing occurs after *n* characters.  I've found that a combination approach like this works well in an IDE type environment.

One thing to remember is, if you do this, don't mess with the text control's insertion point upon finding a syntax error, because errors are inescapable as they type.  I simply show a message in a label:

```
    public override void Recover(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e)
    {
        IToken token = recognizer.CurrentToken;
        string message = string.Format("parse error at line {0}, position {1} right before {2} ", token.Line, token.Column, GetTokenErrorDisplay(token));
        BasicEnvironment.SyntaxError = message;
```

In my use environment, the timer usually governs when it goes off; with a value of 800 milliseconds and 10 characters I get great results, with the timer usually governing when the parse kicks off.

Comment: JLH, thanks so much for your answer. I thought I'd hit an impasse with this issue, but you've made me see that there are alternatives to incremental parsing. One question-- what was your value for n? Also does m = 400?

Comment: @JamesKo I edited my answer with the current values.  Had to check to refresh my memory.  ;) Hope this is adequate for an "Accept"  Cheers.

Comment: JLH, I will accept your answer in a few days. Since this is such a broad question, I don't want to deter other people from answering. I am deeply grateful for your answer, however, which is why I've already upvoted you.

Comment: JLH, just curious why did you choose to trigger a re-parse once the user enters a line terminator/separator?

Comment: @JamesKo Only for line-oriented languages.  Again, in real use, the timer usually kicks off the parse.  But line ending?  Think assembly language or other line-oriented grammar.  Line terminator is a perfect time to parse.

Answer (score 1):

@JLH basically stated the approach I'm using as well but I wanted to add some things you might want to watch out for:
First fo all I would do the parsing in a different Thread than the UI thread of your editor in order to prevent the situation in which the parser started at the same time the user decided to continue coding. If you are using a different thread the user can continue coding without even noticing that the parser is running in the background. of course you need to use some sort of mechanism that will either cancel the parsing in such a situation or at least don't do anything in the editor with the produced parse tree as it is already obsolte.

The next thing is that I have found is that ANTLR can get really slow on medium sized files (~100 lines). And with really slow I mean that the parsing can take up to 20 seconds! That can be prevent by switchung ANTLR's default parsing algorithm to `SLL` and using a BailoutStrategy so that it doen't try to recover from syntax errors. If that occurs you have to parse the whole thing again with the normal `LL` mode in order to check if it is really a syntax error or just something that `SLL` can't deal with.
With that approach I reduced the parse time in some of my files from ~20s to ~1s.

You can habe a look at a working (for sure not perfect) implementation of this in the [source code](https://github.com/Krzmbrzl/SQDev/blob/f31cc8664b2797596188e5609ac7672bc89e3abd/plugin/Raven.SQDev.SQFEditor/src/raven/sqdev/editors/sqfeditor/SQF_Editor.java#L298) of mine (though it's in java but the principle should be the same).

Comment: Raven: Thanks for the extra info on switching the parsing algorithm, I had no idea about that problem (I haven't tested much with files that contain grammatical errors yet). I have one question-- what mechanism can I use to "cancel parsing"? .NET has a `CancellationToken` type that allows you to cancel an asynchronous method before it's finished, and I think that'd be just what we're looking for here. However, since ANTLR is written in Java (and ANTLR for C# mirrors the API of the original), I don't think the parser supports cancellation like that. Have you come up with such a mechanism?

Comment: Nope I haven*'t found a way of cancelling the ANTLR parser. What I do is setting a flag in the parsing thread and after ANTLR has finished it's parsing I check that flag and if it is true I don't process the parseTree. It's not the best solutionbut it does the job...

Comment: @JamesKo Perhaps you should look into the Bailout strategy or a custom lexer that tolerates no errors and stops at the first one.  Search here on SO or ask a specific question.  I use these techniques in my domain-specific languages to avoid continuation of lexing/parsing after even the tiniest error.